# RegEx: does not end with "hede"

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

[Updated with the answers]

1. does not **start** with "hede": `^(?!hede).*$`
2. does not **contain** "hede": `^((?!hede).)*$`
3. does not **end** with "hede": `(?s)^.*+(?<!hede)$`

All 3 expressions work.

Checking:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s)^.*+(?<!hede)$");
assertTrue( p.matcher("hede obsolete").matches()); //ok 
assertTrue( p.matcher("obsolete hede obsolete").matches()); //ok
assertFalse(p.matcher("obsolete hede").matches()); //ok
```

Comment: Why don't you just reverse your logic? Instead of trying and writing a regex like that, just invert the regex and the test

Comment: Some API accepts a string with regexp, so you can't invert result with Java.

Comment: I strongly advise to read my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some words about `^.*(?<!hede)$` solution suggested by @vks: it would be good under one condition - using *possessive quantifier with `.*`*, `.*+`. The updated regex will look like:

```
(?s)^.*+(?<!hede)$
       ^
```

Also, the inline modifier `(?s)` can be used to force a `.` to match a newline symbol, so that we can also check if a multiline string ends with `hede`.

**The plus symbol makes a huge difference.** Since the `(?<!hede)` look-behind with `.*` pattern in front is checking for `hede` absence each time a character is tested, this regex is not quite stable. A possessive quantifier will make sure no backtracking occurs after the whole string/line is matched, and only after it there is 1 check for `hede` absence is performed.

As an alternative, you may use a negative look-ahead right at the beginning to check if a string ends with `hede` (this version can be used with `matcher.find`):

```
(?s)^(?!.*hede$)
```

or, to match the whole line/string that does not end with `hede`:

```
(?s)^(?!.*hede$).*
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tD0dU9/2)

[IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/lOd7aR), example for `matches()` (without `$` at the end as the whole string must match):

```
System.out.println("A string with hede".matches("(?s)^(?!.*hede$).*")); // => false
System.out.println("A string without".matches("(?s)^(?!.*hede$).*")); // => true
```

Comment: I examined Friedl's "Mastering Regular Expressions" about backtracking and undurstood high performance of your regex. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `lookbehind` for that.

```
^.*(?<!hede)$
```

or you can use

```
^.*+(?<!hede)$
```

with possessive quantifier as suggested by [@stribizhev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/stribizhev)

Comment: The test is passed. Thanks!)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, wouldn't it be easier (in this situation) to search for strings that _do_ contain the search string and just `not` the `if`? (e.g. in perl `if s !~ /.*hede.*/`, `if s !~ /^hede/`, `if s !~ /hede$/`

Comment: @Arc676 we have built in `lookbehind` for that.......the code would be much cleaner :)

Comment: Just a note that a look-behind - although cleaner by its looks - is more resource consuming. Especially in this case, when each character is checked if it is not preceded with `hede`. Just put the regex into an online tester and see for yourself. My solution (`^(?!.*hede$).*$`) is much quicker. Here is when [catastrophic backtracking will occur with this solution](https://regex101.com/r/dK9bR5/1).

Comment: @stribizhev didnt know possessive quantifiers existed in java.Thanx updated

Answer (score 2):

You can use this *negative lookahead*:

```
^(?!.*hede$).*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zV3pW8/1)